# How to Assign binary datatype value of sqlserver 2008 into long variable in c# in Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate

In one of the project I have been working, I found that binary values are being stored in binary(50) data type column in database.
For instance 1,2,4,8,16 and so on are stored in binary(50) data column in database using their hexadecimal equivalent.

Can I retrieve those value in NHibernate to a long data type.

Please note that Nhibernate requires binary(50) of sql server to be taken as byte[].

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Implement IUserType and specify your class as "type" in the mappings of that column.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom type by using AbstractType and IParameterizedType these are in NHibernate.Type namespace.